Blender Assets Keeps Resetting
I recently got some Blender assets, and I want to keep them in a different location. I changed the filepath in settings to the new folder, and I added the assets to the path as well. When I do so, the assets are showing up, but when I close the project and reopen, they're gone. Is there anyway to have them be permanently loaded up or do I have to load them in everytime?

What does the Asset Browser say, are they stored in the general assets or in the current file? Could you show the Asset Browser, the path settings you are using etc.?

It sounds like you need to save your preferences. With the Preferences window open, click the hamburger menu in the bottom left, and click “save preferences” to make the settings the default when starting up Blender.
